# Passing a value from a feature file into a JSON body in specflow c#

Tags: c#, json, replace, restsharp, specflow

```
Scenario: Create System X Report
Given I have accessed System x's endpoint
When I make a Post request for the report 7890 with the title Report number 7890
Then I get a response
Then I verify the response
```

That is my scenario in my feature file, I want to pass "7890" & "Report number 7890" into this JSON body, which is on the post request within the Step Definition.

```
[When(@"I make a Post request for the report (.*) with the title Report number (.*)"), Scope(Tag = "post")]
    public void WhenIMakeAPostRequest(int report, String reporttitle)
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("upload_with_associations", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "report_urn\": \"{report}        " +
            "\"_links\": {\n            \"curies\": title\": \"**{reporttitle}**                 \"href\": \"https://report-service-apps.domain/docs/{rel}\",\n       " +
            "             ,\n        " +
            "    \"get-report-documents\": [\n                {\n                    \"href\": \"/api/report/<report_urn>/documents\"\n             " +
                   ]\n        },\n        \"report_urn\": \"**{report}**\",\n        \"report_source\": {\n          " +
             "          get-report-documents , ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        statuscode = response.StatusCode;

    }
```

So I am passing in the values from the feature file into the step definition and then I am trying to replace the value in the json body as {report}, but I know this is wrong , so how can I pass the values into the json body?

```
[When(@"I make a Post request for the report (.*) with the title Report number (.*)"), Scope(Tag = "post")]
public void WhenIMakeAPostRequest(int report, String reporttitle)


request.AddParameter("application/json", "report_urn\": \"{report}
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? I would argue that is one valid approach.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment when I am putting {report} into the json body ... the int report is coming up as unused .... and test is not passing

Comment: Hey... I really don't know about this sorry bro. Hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some json serializer, for example **Newtonsoft.Json**.

1. Create a model (or several models) for the request body
2. Create an instance of that model and apply incoming parameters to that model.
3. Mark properties of that model by attribute `[JsonProperty] and use the name from your json
4. Serialize it and use string instead of existing json string

Comment: Could I just use JObject method and somehow add that string into that and in the json body that I have .. call it in that using {}

Comment: You can avoid it if there is a model with one property and attribute `[JsonProperty("report_urn")]`. So the serialization result can be put into `AddParameter` method like this: `request.AddParameter("application/json", report, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

Answer (score 0):

The idea goes like this

1. Take the parameter from feature
2. Create a templete json with a identifier for dynamic usage
3. Create a a script for read the items as map and replace the identifier by value from feature file
   Pli will post the code shortly